# How to expand LVM group by adding new physical device

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I'm having space issues on one server; the disk layout is setup so root device is on a volume group:

```
#vgscan
Found volume group "VolGroup00" using metadata type lvm2

#pvscan
PV /dev/xvdb1   VG lvm          lvm2 [322.26 GB / 107.26 GB free]
PV /dev/xvda2   VG VolGroup00   lvm2 [29.19 GB / 0    free]
Total: 2 [351.45 GB] / in use: 2 [351.45 GB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

#lvscan
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00' [27.16 GB] inherit (my root)
ACTIVE '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01' [2.03 GB] inherit  (swap)
```

As you see, no space left on LogVol01. I'm looking for a 'quick' way to add more space
I can add new physical device but don't know how to tell LVM to add this to the group.

Do I need to restart and boot livecd in order to do this operation ?

(This server is running in production and i really need to figure out what to do)

thank you for your answers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a physical volume to an existing volume group with the command
`vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/drive_name`

Stretching out an existing logical volume over the new physical volume requires `lvextend`. I recommend reading [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/addpvstovg.html), there are many things to consider when extending a logical volume.

After extending the logical volume you can resize the partition with `resize2fs`, but be sure to check it for errors first using `fsck`.

In this case the filesystem is the root filesystem, so a filesystem check can't be performed without rebooting. Creating a file in the root called forcefsck will make sure that fsck is run at the next boot. `touch /forcefsck`

Source: the [tldp pages on LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/), specifically the pages on [vgextend](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/addpvstovg.html) , and [lvextend](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html).
These documentation pages are an excellent source of information on LVM.

* this post was heavily edited based on the comments.

Comment: Thanks fell upon this too; now i have added the device I see the correct size on the vgscan but when I try to resize2fs it says that the device is already XXX blocks long. Nothing to do. In 'df' it shows the previous size.

Comment: the partition is ext3.

Comment: Try running `fsck.ext3` on the partition, see if there is something wrong with the filesystem.

Comment: on a running mounted root system ???

Comment: You should probably take it down, boot with a live cd and unmount it. I'm sorry this isn't the quick solution it was supposed to be, but there's not helping it if resize2fs won't resize the partition.

Comment: Is there a way to 'mark' the device to be fsck on next reboot ?

Comment: Having a file in the root called forcefsck just that. `touch /forcefsck`

Comment: did that; fsck forced but still not detecting my new space.

Comment: I've been reading up on the tldp pages I linked in my answer. Turns out stretching a partition out to a second physical volume requires the use of lvextend. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html This unfortunately requires another reboot.

Comment: Right ! Missed that out ! now resizing live (thanks to CentOS !) thank you very much !

Comment: @kenny.r can you edit your answer to contain the steps required so it's easier to see rather than having to read though the comments please.

Comment: @Iain great idea, done.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the new PV from the new VG, add it to the existing VG, and expand the LV and FS.

Comment: I haven't added the new PV yet; can you please describe the whole process with examples ?